# (Python) Find Peak Value of 2D Array by using recursion

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

```
def find(lst):
    m=len(lst[0])
    n=len(lst)
    j=m//2

    currentRow=[]
    i=0
    while i< len(lst):
        currentRow.append(lst[i][j])
        i+=1

    i=currentRow.index(max(currentRow))

    if j>0 and lst[i][j]<lst[i][j-1]:
        return find([currentRow[:j] for currentRow in lst])
    elif j<m-1 and lst[i][j]<lst[i][j+1]:
        return find([currentRow[j:] for currentRow in lst])
    else:
        return lst[i][j]
lst=[]
while True:
    try:
        lst.append([int(num) for num in input().split()])
    except EOFError:
        break
maxNum=find(lst)
for i in range(len(lst)):
    for j in range(len(lst[0])):
        if lst[i][j]==maxNum:
            print((i,j))
```

```
Input:
10 8 10 10
14 13 12 11
15 9 11 21
16 17 19 20
```

```
Expected Output:
(2, 3)
```

However, when I run my code, the compiler display `"IndexError: list index out of range"`. As a beginner learner, I have no idea what's wrong despite debugging for few hours. Thanks for your help!

Comment: *"debugging for few hours"*: then I think you are not debugging. Debugging means you run a debugger, set breakpoints, step through the code with the debugger, inspect variables, up to the point where the error occurs, so that you have complete information of all variables and call state at the moment the error occurs, and have had the opportunity to step statement by statement to that point and see how it got there.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. For which input do you get an error?

Comment: avoid recursive functions, and here is why:  https://youtu.be/1podU0jN4aU

Comment: The IndexError you get means you're trying to access an index in a list that does not exist. I wasn't able to use your code to produce the error even. It would help if you would provide better names for your variables and functions and put in comments so we'd know what you're trying to achieve. I have a hunch of what you want to achieve, but you need to tell us what you're doing in your code.

Comment: @trincot Thanks for replying to my post. Also, apologise for my beginner mistake, misusing the wrong term. The sample input is:
10 8 10 10 (new line)
14 13 12 11 (new line)
15 9 11 21 (new line)
16 17 19 20
And, the expected output is:
(2, 3)
I hope it answers what you are asking.

Comment: @D.L Hi, thanks for your suggestion. However, this is a question for me to practice recursion. I do understand your concern in the pros and cons. However, the my main objective here is to practice my implementation of recursion.

Comment: I cannot reproduce a problem. I ran your code with that input and it returns (2, 3). Please confirm that `lst` is loaded correctly and has the expected values.

Comment: @AlexIxeras Hi, thanks for reaching out. For this code, I am trying to find the peak value of a 2D list. And, I feel weird, as I could compile it using USACO Online IDE, however, the IndexError occurs by using Pycharm or VSCode. I have checked my for loop range and also index of my list, but to no avail.

Comment: @CHINKENGHOW I'm trying this on a bare command line via python3. When you see you need to make changes (as with your sample) input and providing more information on your environment, just edit your question (via "Edit" to the left of your "card" below your question). – I understand you want to find the peak value in your 2D list (which is a matrix, right?), whereby peak means it's higher than both its left and right neighbour. Can you confirm?

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Answer (score 0):

```
def find(lst,i=0,j=0,v=None,coo=(0,0)):
    if i == h:
        return coo
    k = lst[i][j]
    if k>v:
        v = k
        coo = (i,j)
    if j<w:
        return find(lst,i=i,j=j+1,v=v,coo=coo)
    else:
        return find(lst,i=i+1,j=0,v=v,coo=coo)


lst=[]
while True:
    try:
        lst.append([int(num) for num in input().split()])
    except EOFError:
        break

h = len(lst)
w = len(lst[0]) - 1
coordinate=find(lst,v=lst[0][0])

print(coordinate)
```

Comment: Don’t be surprised if you get no positive responses, or even a few downvotes, for a code-only answer. A good answer should explain what the problem was and how you fixed it.